# Which professions use a lot of derivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus

I'm on my 1st year in college and just started learning calculus. I really enjoy using and calculating derivatives and integrals. I'm wondering which professions get to play with those daily?

Comment: Students. Integral-Bee participants. Test-Writers.

Comment: Mathematics teacher.

Comment: Nobody just does derivatives and integrals all day, but become a researcher in engineering or physics or math or machine learning and you can hope to use interesting math in your research.

Comment: I think that the point in learning calculus, is **not** to be able to quickly integrate some function with pen and paper, but rather to understand the principles. These principles are very important in, for example, engineering and research. When you're out of school, you can always ask Wolfram Alpha to integrate a function for you.